# Tuning fork shape

Tags: acoustics, vibrations

Hope all is well!

Is it absolutely necessary for a tuning fork to have that well know "U" geometric shape? How important is the geometric shape?

Also, does the mass of that tuning fork play a vital role in its performance?

Can we design a rectangular solid block made of the same material as a tuning fork and later use it for a similar purpose/functionality as a U shaped tuning fork?

Ty for the replies!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning_fork mentions a couple of reasons: purity of tone and being able to hold it without damping down the vibration (the handle is at a node).

Comment: I have no proper actual math behind this belief, but my intuition is that hard corners in a boundary will make Laplacian modes have dissonant relationships, and good resonators must have rounded boundaries that make harmonies "flow good". Whatever that means. So if this belief is correct, a rectangular or hard-angled boundary will always have badly sounding resonant modes